# Android: Copy File From Assets/Raw dir. To Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

So basically I'm working on GFX tool for pubg mobile which copy file from app (assets) to another location (internal storage)

Main: So the problem is I'm new in android development as well as in kotlin and java too and i dont know how can i copy file from app (assets) to another location (internal storage) when i click button on my app so please if anyone know please help it's really appreciate

I am writing an Android application and I need to copy 2 files into the device's internal storage. Currently I am able to run my application after manually copying these two files under the device's "/data/data/[my_package_name]/files" folder using DDMS. I need to put these two files into that folder(or any folder) while my application is being installed on the device. The tip here says files within the "res/raw/" directory will be deployed to the device and will be accessible through `openRawResource()`, but it doesn't tell where these files will be put inside the internal memory. To summerize, I have two files in my project folder (assets, raw, any other folder) and I need to copy these two inside a path of internal memory. How can I achieve this? Do I need any permissions included to my AndroidManifest.xml?

Thank you in advance

**Edit : Answer Found**

So basically it will copy all the data from Asset folder to Internal Storage (Download Folder of Android), Call the copyAsset() function in onCreate.

```
private void copyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
    }
    for (String filename : files) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = assetManager.open(filename);

            String outDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/";

            File outFile = new File(outDir, filename);

            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
        }
    }
} 

 private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `getAssets().open(...)` on some `Context`, where `...` is the path within `assets/` that you want to open. That gives you an `InputStream`. Create a `FileOutputStream` on your desired destination. Then call `copyTo()` on the `InputStream`, supplying the `FileOutputStream`. [This viewmodel](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/blob/v2.0/PdfProvider/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/pdfprovider/MainMotor.kt) (covered in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack)) illustrates the technique, though it also deals with coroutines and viewstates, which you may or may not need.

Comment: `which replace file from app (assets) to another location (internal storage)` Replace or move are impossible. You can only read and copy that file.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you already have in your question instead of describing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically it will copy all the data from Asset folder to Internal Storage (Download Folder of Android), Call the copyAsset() function in onCreate.

```
private void copyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
    }
    for (String filename : files) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = assetManager.open(filename);

            String outDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/";

            File outFile = new File(outDir, filename);

            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
        }
    }
} 

 private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).